# Very general question about creating website to communicate with my Raspberry Pi server

Tags: database, server, raspberry-pi, webserver

This is a very general question, but I have this idea of a project I would like to work on, as a learning process but also to customize the product totally to my needs. I know some Java programming and have made before a simple local Java application that used MySQL server.

What I want to do is:

1. Buy my self a Raspberry Pi + hard drive and use it as a server for my family pictures - and my movies/music
2. Create a web interface where I (or other users with login credentials) can upload pictures to the server (use tags, dates whatever I will come up with), search and download pictures/videos (one they have access to).
3. I would like to be able to access my music and movies i.e. via a plex server.

My question is first:
Can I run this all on the same Raspberry? Webserver, the database server for the pictures/videos, and then i.e. Plex for the movies?

Then the big question, the steps, and the stuff I need for the picture server part:

- What language, aid, stuff, should I use and get to know how to      use for the actual website (also to make it secure like use let's encrypt for SSL...)
- Then I need a webserver on my Raspberry, right?
- And database server that the webserver connects to?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the same a while ago and I used the help of [this areticle](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/raspberry-pi-plex-media-server/)

In addition to this, if you want to host a website (for login authentication) and then redirect it to the plex media server, you can buy a cheap domain and a free hosting or create your own hosting by the steps below,

Install the web server software:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server mysql-client
sudo chown -R yourusername /var/www
sudo chgrp -R yourusername /var/www
ln -s /var/www/html ~/html
```

At this point it's all up and running. Going to the Pi's IP address in a web browser should reveal the default Apache page. That page is stored in /var/www/html/index.html, and also accessable through the link you made as ~/html/index.html. Assuming you want the web server to be public, you probably want to setup port forwarding on your router (TCP port 80) and use a domain name and dynamic DNS service so people can type in a .com
instead of an IP that might change over time.

You can use the google domains to purchase .COM (which is what I used) and setup the dynamic DNS service they offer:

Login to https://domains.google.com/
In the rows of domain names, click on the DNS icon for the domain you want to setup
In the Synthetic Records section, select Dynamic DNS
For the subdomain, use "@" (without the quotes) for no subdomain (like when someones goes to yourdomain.com instead of [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com))
Then make another record for the "www" (without quotes) subdomain
Click on the > icon next to each record, then click View Credentials

You can use software like ddclient to notify Google when your IP changes, or you can keep things simple and just visit a specially-crafted URL periodically to keep Google up-to-date. Here's a simple script to visit that URL and record its response to a text file. Be sure to make the script executable:

```
nano ~/dns_update_script.sh
    wget https://username:password@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=yourdomain.com -qO dns_update_results.txt
    wget https://username:password@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=www.yourdomain.com -qO- >> dns_update_results.txt
    echo " Last run: `date`" >> dns_update_results.txt
chmod +x ~/dns_update_script.sh
```

The script downloads the web pages to the text file (the first wget creates the text file, the second wget appends to the text file) and then I also append the current date and time to the text file.

Setup a cron job to run the script at the start of every hour:

```
crontab -e
    0 * * * * ~/dns_update_script.sh
```

Using Virtual Hosts to Serve Multiple Domains
A single computer can serve multiple domains. Apache supports this and calls it a "Virtual Host." You can repeat the following steps for as many domains as needed:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.conf
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.yourdomain.com
        ServerAlias yourdomain.com *.yourdomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yourdomain
    </VirtualHost>

sudo mkdir /var/www/yourdomain
sudo chown -R yourusername /var/www/yourdomain
sudo chgrp -R yourusername /var/www/yourdomain
ln -s /var/www/yourdomain ~/yourdomain

sudo a2ensite yourdomain
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Using Swish-SFTP to Copy Files to the Pi
After installing Swish-SFTP, there will be a "Swish" device listed in File Explorer > This PC. Double-click it, then choose "Add SFTP Connection" near the top of the window. After making a connection you can drag-and-drop files between Windows and the Pi.

That's it. You now have a web server that requires less than 5 watts of power to run, and occupies hardly any space in your home.